# Problem while updating modules

Tags: updating

I'm running a Drupal website for a while but suddenly and for an unknown reason the website become unable to update modules via the back office.
The download of the modules goes good but when I click to the button to update the database I got an error page and when I see the recent reports logs I have that:

```
UpdaterException: Unable to determine the type of the source directory. in Updater::factory() (line 99 of ../www/includes/updater.inc).
```

Is there any solution for that problem?
**Notice**: I'm using Zeus server instead of Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the directory it's expecting the source to come from doesn't exist. Here's the snippet of code which causes the exception to be thrown.

```
if (is_dir($source)) {
  $updater = self::getUpdaterFromDirectory($source);
}
else {
  throw new UpdaterException(t('Unable to determine the type of the source directory.'));
}
```

When updating this is the default directory: `$directory = 'temporary://update-extraction-' . _update_manager_unique_identifier();`

Make sure your defined temporary folder in the file system can be written to by Drupal.

If all else fails, manually update your modules via file transfer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful ansewer; i just changed the permission and everything goes ok; thank yoy again